# String or binary data would be truncated. — even though the column length was increased

Tags: sql-server

I am having an issue with SQL Server where I need to make a column bigger, and I thought I had, but then I can't fit in it data bigger than the initial size of the column.

The column `[columnName]` initially was `VARCHAR(50)` and I used the command below to change the size to `VARCHAR(100)`:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tableName 
    ALTER COLUMN columnName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL;
```

In the table design view I can see that the size is now **100**.

Despite this, I still get the error

> String or binary data would be truncated.

when trying to fit data that exceeds the initial space of 50 bytes.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps the data is longer than 100 characters?

Comment: Then there's still a `VARCHAR(50)` out there somewhere. A stored procedure parameter? A view with a trigger? A parameterized command? (Also, check the usual silly mistakes of not working on the server/table you think you're working on.)

Comment: If you're running a `insert into ... select` command, it's simple to see what the problem is by running `select ... into #tmp` instead and looking what the column types are for the generated table.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thank you for that comment, it helped understand the problem. It turns out part of the error message, which I did not deem important when posing this question, mentioned a procedure. This procedure is actually an encrypted trigger. I suppose it's futile to change the column size if I have a trigger that will inspect the update and still limit to the original size.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your insert statement is something like:

```
insert into dbo.tableName (
    ...,
    columnName,
    ...
    )
select ...,
    columnName,
    ...
from dbo.anotherTableName
```

Then, use this SQL to find out the largest value you are trying to insert into that column:

```
select max(len(columnName)) as minVarcharLengthRequired
from dbo.anotherTableName
```

And then use something larger than that for the alter table statement.